# Visa for holiday to New Zealand

Tags: visas, new-zealand, irish-citizens

I worked in New Zealand for 3 years left in 2015.
Do I need to get a visa to go back for a holiday ?
I'm from Ireland.

Comment: You're an Irish citizen, yes?
What visa/permit etc did you use to work in NZ?

Comment: Yes Irish .i first had a 1 year working holiday and then got sponsored for 2 years.

Answer (score 6):

**No you don't need a visa**, not if you're staying less than 3 months.

Ireland is on the list of [visa waiver countries](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/tools-and-information/general-information/visa-waiver-countries) for New Zealand.

[image]